# Fluent NHibernate automap reference key

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I've recently updated my project to FNH 1.3.0.727 and NH 3.3.0.4000 via NuGet from versions 1.3.0.717 and 3.2.0.4000. Using automap, the generated XML prior to update looks like this:

```
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="APP.Domain.Module, APP.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="Module">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="ModuleId" />
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one class="APP.Domain.Product, APP.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Product">
      <column name="ProductId" />
    </many-to-one>
    <joined-subclass name="APP.Domain.Audit.Trail, APP.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <key>
        <column name="TrailId" />
      </key>
      <bag cascade="all" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="Arguments">
        <key>
          <column name="TrailId" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="APP.Domain.Audit.Argument, APP.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </bag>
      <property name="Action" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <column name="Action" />
      </property>
      <property name="Date" type="System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <column name="Date" />
      </property>
      <property name="Workflow" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <column name="Workflow" />
      </property>
      <property name="Identity" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <column name="[Identity]" />
      </property>
    </joined-subclass>
  </class>
```

and after update:

```
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="APP.Domain.Module, APP.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="`Module`">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="ModuleId" />
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one class="APP.Domain.Product, APP.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Product">
      <column name="ProductId" />
    </many-to-one>
    <joined-subclass name="APP.Domain.Audit.Trail, APP.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <key>
        <column name="TrailId" />
        <column name="ModuleId" />
      </key>
      <bag cascade="all" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="Arguments">
        <key>
          <column name="TrailId" />
          <column name="TrailId" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="APP.Domain.Audit.Argument, APP.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </bag>
      <property name="Name" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <column name="Name" />
      </property>
      <property name="Date" type="System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <column name="Date" />
      </property>
      <property name="Workflow" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <column name="Workflow" />
      </property>
      <property name="Identity" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <column name="[Identity]" />
      </property>
    </joined-subclass>
  </class>
```

There is no composite keys in my model, everything was right, and now I'm gettin exception `"Foreign key (FK4B9386BFF4D27734:Argument [TrailId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (Trail [TrailId, ModuleId])"`.

Am I missing something for the new versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IReferenceConvention instead overriding GetKeyName in ForeignKeyconvention class solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem resides in the combination of conventions and overrides. Former version overrides the key columns correctly in each case (foreign, joined, hasmany, manytomany, etc), but now is adding them. bug?